# When to set online for presence detection using Firebase Realtime database, Firestore and functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm implementing presence detection based on document. There is a thing I can't get it. Why do they set a user online at that time in the document by Firebase?

I considered the right code is

```js
    firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() == false) {
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);
            return;
        };
        // I thought they should set a user online here.
        userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
        userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForFirestore);

        userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {

        });
    });
```

. On the other hand, the document shows

```js
    firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() == false) {
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);
            return;
        };

        userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
            // but the document does here.
            userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForFirestore);
        });
    });
```

found in the document.

I thought they should set a user to be online when they get connected. It seems that when they detect offline, they set `isOfflineForDatabase` and then set `isOnlineForDatabase` and `isOnlineForFirestore`. What's going on? Why is my code not good? Actually, their code works fine.

Thank you for reading.

- [The document source code from github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/854595932e2b0e2c7a9c1de16985f185cd2a9cac/presence-firestore/public/index.js#L68-L112)

  [Build presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence)

Answer (score 0):

I understood.

```js
userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect()
```

returns `onDisconnect` instance.

```js
userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase)
```

returns `Future<void>`

So,

```js
       .then(function() {
            // but the document does here.
            userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForFirestore);
        });
```

is executed immediately when executing this line. Also, All actions should be executed after setting onDisconect listener.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you got from the documentation, the user is only set as online when the server has acknowledged that it will mark them as offline when they're gone. In your code, there is no such dependency.

In the vast majority of the cases the two pieces of code will likely lead to the same result. But if there is a problem with registering the `onDisconnect` handler in your code, the user will still be marked as online, while the code from the documentation  will not mark them as online.